# Getting duplicate records from 2 sql tables

Tags: db2

I have 2 SQL tables

Table #1

| account | product | expiry-date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | prod1 | 2021-01-30 |
| 102 | prod2 | 2021-02-20 |
| 103 | prod3 | 2021-03-09 |
| 103 | prod3 | 2021-03-19 |
| 104 | prod4 | 2021-03-15 |
| 105 | prod5 | 2021-04-23 |
| 105 | prod5 | 2021-04-24 |
| 106 | prod6 | 2021-04-25 |

Table #2

| account |
| --- |
| 101 |
| 106 |

From the above 2 tables I want to get only unmatched records from Table1 and avoid duplicate records.

Result:

| account | product | expiry-date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 102 | prod2 | 2021-02-20 |
| 103 | prod3 | 2021-03-09 |
| 104 | prod4 | 2021-03-15 |
| 105 | prod5 | 2021-04-23 |

Below query I tried but I am getting duplicate records, because expiry date is unique on account. I am getting below records in my output

SQL query I tried:

```
 select distinct (a.account, a.product, a.expiry-date) 
 from table1 a 
 where a.account not in (select account from table2)
```

Result:

| account | product | expiry-date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 102 | prod2 | 2021-02-20 |
| 103 | prod3 | 2021-03-09 |
| 103 | prod3 | 2021-03-19 |
| 104 | prod4 | 2021-03-15 |
| 105 | prod5 | 2021-04-23 |
| 105 | prod5 | 2021-04-24 |

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: Though I can't answer for the other RDBMS you spammed, in SQL Server `DISTINCT` is **not** a function, it's an operator that applies to the *entire* scope of the statement it is defined it. As such `distinct (a.account, a.product, a.expiry-date)` could be very misleading.

Comment: yes, it is taking expiry-date as unique record, but I need to compare account column from both tables and ignore remaining columns. But in the results I need to get all columns from table1. Like I gave in last table(Result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same query using aggregation:

```
 SELECT a.account
  ,a.product
  ,MIN(a.expiry) expiry
 FROM table1 a
 WHERE a.account NOT IN (
    SELECT account
    FROM table2
    )
 GROUP BY a.account
   ,a.product
```

Comment: when I am executing the above query I am getting COLUMN OR EXPRESSION IN THE SELECT LIST IS NOT VALID, SQL code =  -122.

I removed distinct from my query and added group by .

Comment: Try add an alias to Min column, i will edit the answer

Comment: It is working fine if I remove group by, if I add group by then it is giving that error SQL code = -122

Comment: did you take `MIN(a.expiry)` on the select or you left it `a.expiry`, it won't work with only `a.expiry`

Comment: I kept as a.expiry, i didn't added MIN

Comment: you should add it, or changed to another aggregation function that suits your need

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240299/discussion-between-boba-poorna-and-dourayd-tlili).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an anti-join and then `ROW_NUMBER()` For example:

```
select *
from (
  select a.*, row_number() over(partition by accoun order by expiry) as rn
  from table1 a
  left join table2 b on b.account = a.account
  where b.account is null
) x
where rn = 1
```